# Error: Your database or project contains a missing or broken reference to the file UTILITY.ACCDA

Tags: ms-access

1. I am trying to make an exe file for an access database using software SSE            Setup for installation.
2. The exe file successfully runs and installs the file on a different PC, but when I run it I get an error "Your database  or project contains a missing or broken reference to the file UTILITY.ACCDA'.

[image]

3. Going back to the original Access file I notice in the file VBA that a different project gets (utility) created when any form has a class module associate with it. NO such project is created when the Access database has a class modules or object of Access not having  supporting VBA code. Attached in screenshot

[image]

4. What is it that needs to be changed? I have tried renaming file as mentioned in this [link](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2581301/acc2010-you-receive-an-error-in-microsoft-access-using-the-built-in-wi&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1526379889083000&usg=AFQjCNF8f9B1tzICNC-hDVPi_AJ6SoDb4A) .
5. I have made the Access file on Access Office 365 and am trying to run on a machine which has lower version of Access installed

Please assist how to have my access database working

Answer (score 1):

UTILITY.accda is one of the add-ins that's present in Access by default, and is used internally for things like tooltips, the *Zoom* form that you can popup in the query folder, and more.

Apparently, your database has a reference to it. Perhaps it uses the `BuilderZoom` function to make zoom boxes pop up?

You can do three things:

1. Under *Tools* -> *References*, uncheck *utility*. That removes the reference. Under *Debug*, recompile your database, and check if any errors occur.
2. Include *UTILITY.accda* in your setup file. It's located in your Access setup folder, under *ACCWIZ/UTILITY.accda*. Full path for a default 32-bits Office 365 installation should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ACCWIZ. However, you might run into trouble setting a relative reference, which means your installer needs to place this file on a fixed location.
3. Use VBA to dynamically determine the path to UTILITY.accda and fix the broken references. A useful resource for that path is: [Microsoft Support page about VBA and references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308340/how-to-check-and-remove-incorrect-project-references-in-the-visual-bas). You can determine the path to the current Access installation by using `SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir)`

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu *Add-ins* and check that the *Utility* isn't added.

Then open a new database and import all objects from your current application, except the utility project.

Of course, if your application actually uses the utility add-in, locate it in your Access program folder and include it in the setup.

Comment: regarding your comment

The utility(UTILITY) is automatically created, I haven't added it!  As I mentioned it is coming from the forms having VBA

@ Go to menu Add-ins and check that the Utility isn't added.
Unable to locate the 'utility' 

@ Then open a new database and import all objects from your current application, except the utility project.
Tried, as soon as I copy the forms having VBA, 'utility' automatically comes 

@ Of course, if your application actually uses the utility add-in, locate it in your Access program folder and include it in the setup.
Where to locate it from?

Comment: It should be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OfficeXX\ACCWIZ` where XX is related to your Office version